# Genetic alghorithm / Linear-rank selector , the problem with meaning of the variables

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have the equation of probability of choicing an induvidual in Linear-rank selector.

```
P(i) = (1/N) * (n− + (n+ − n− )* ( i−1 / N−1) )
```

tell me please , what is  **n-**  and  **n+**  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n-/N is the probability of the worst individual to be selected and n+/N the probability of the best individual to be selected. As the population size is held constant, the conditions n+ = 2 - n- and n- >= 0 must be fulfilled. Note that all individuals get a different rank, i.e., a different selection probability, even if the have the same fitness value.

See [A Comparison of Selection Schemes used in Evolutionary Algorithms (1997)](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.15.9584)

Comment: What is the difference beetwen  i  and  n-  or  n+  ,  could you give me example with numbers ?

Comment: Your population, P, contains  N elements and is sorted according its fitness function. i is the index of the ith individual of the population.

Comment: So what is  n-  ?

Comment: As I said, 'n-/N' is the selection probability of the worst individual. So n- is a measure for selecting the worst individual. And n+ is a measure for selecting the best individual.